# Load GIF to the div using jQuery attr div

Tags: jquery, html, load, captcha, attr

```
    $('#captcha').attr('src', 'captcha.php?' + (new Date()).getTime());
});
</script>
```

And it works wonderfully, the `img` with `id=captcha` is hiding but the loading GIF doesn't want to show when I uncomment `load('#loading')` or write something similar to this. Any advice?

Comment: Not sure to understand, when do you want the loading gif to be shown? When do you want it to be hidden?

Comment: I want to load gif before captcha is shown. it is normal loading gif. but  I want to load it into the same div in which there is captcha. sorry for my english, friend. LOAD GIF AFTER HIDING #captcha in $('#captcha').hide(); or... instead $('#captcha').hide(); load a gif to <img id="captcha">

Comment: only to load gif, before captcha showing.

Comment: But as i understand it, you want to set captcha source to 'reload.gif' but in same time, using onload event, set its source to a new captcha image. This is not the right way to do something like this. You should really provide a jsfiddle, I'm completly lost right now

Comment: Hey, I uploaded script to my server. http://lupo24.pl/form_rej.php Just click arrow button to change captcha and You will see that captcha is hiding, but #load gif is not showing. I uploaded there, because I do not know how to make some element in jsfiddle :/

Comment: As I said, Your code looks great, but it still does not work. urg...

Comment: You don't have any element with ID loading, or i cannot find it

Comment: I am so sorry. ID captcha. <img name="captcha_obrazek" id="captcha" src="captcha.php" title="Przepisz kod z obrazka">obrazki/reload.gif</img> It is bcause I am tired today. Really sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try following code:

```
$('#reload').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('isLoading')) return;
    $(this).data('isLoading', true);
    var $container = $('#captcha').parent(),
        $loading = $('<div id="loading"/>');
    $('#captcha').hide(0, function () {
        $loading.prependTo($container)
    }).one('load', function () {
         $('#loading').remove();
        $(this).fadeIn(400, function () {           
            $('#reload').data('isLoading', false);
        });
    }).attr('src', 'captcha.php?' + $.now());
});
```

And use following CSS:

```
#loading {
    float: left; /* <<< add this one */
    background: transparent url(obrazki/reload.gif) no-repeat center center; /* use transparent color, you btw should modificate img to fit with height */
    width: 80px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: This is what I need, and it looks correct. But the problem I have all the time is that the $('#loading').show(); doesn't show. I do not kno why. It hide, but doesn't show #loading gif.

Comment: I know that You understand now. I will tell You as easy as I can. I want to show gif instead of a PINK captcha while it is loading this captcha.

Comment: @glapa.wojciech glad that help you so close question by accepting answer ;)